# netstat in java

Tags: java

How can I use the netstat command in java.

Answer (score 5):

Something like....

```
final String cmd = "netstat -ano";

int pid = -1;

try {
    // Run netstat
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

Once you do something like this you lose platform neutrality - so you have to ask : why are you doing this in Java??

Comment: Would you explain why does doing so make the program lose its platform neutrality(I am pretty new to this concept)?

Comment: Because netstat is a command that is not available on all operating systems ...

Answer (score 1):

If you mean executing netstat command from inside a java program, then what your need is Runtime.exec("command") where command is whatever it is the you want to execute from outside...... [Runtime](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)